# How to create a dictionary from several lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a dictionary from several lists. For example:

```
list1=[11, 12, 13, 14]
list2=[a, b, c, d]
list3=[e, f, g, h]
```

and the result should be:

```
dict={11: [a,e], 12:[b,f], 13:[c,g], 14:[d,h]}
```

Thanks

Comment: How about `dict(zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)))`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: `dict(zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)))` ? (edit: Josh beat me to it)

Comment: Or if you must have lists instead of tuples: `dict(zip(list1, [list(pair) for pair in zip(list2, list3)]))`

Comment: Yes, i have tried with a for loop but i think it's inefficient, I'm going to try with zip, thanks for your answers!

Comment: `dict(zip(list1, map(list, zip(list2, list3))))` to be exact.

Comment: Also, you should avoid calling your dictionary 'dict' because its the built-in keyword to declare a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
obj = {}
for x,y,z in zip(list1,list2,list3):
    obj[x] = [y,z]
```